# Working in a lab over the summer and need book suggestions on learning html web programming

Tags: html, css

This summer I'm helping a doctor create an online brain atlas to store some of his data. He told me to have learned a decent amount of html web programming by the end of the summer and to choose a book that he will order for me. I've done some research and it seems like you have to use CSS along with html to build a website, is that right? I have nearly no other programming experience by the way.

Thanks a Lot

Comment: HTML for structure, semantics and relationships. CSS for presentation. JavaScript for client side programming. Language of choice (Perl in my case) for server side programming. Knowledge of HTTP (the transport protocol) is helpful.

Comment: @spjack - Questions on StackOverflow tend to be more technical and programming-oriented than this; your question may be closed for being off topic, and migrated to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The phrase "storing data" suggests that a database will be needed with a web front end (so you'll need a server side programming language to generate HTML from it), rather then having a set of hand-crafted HTML documents.

Comment: I think [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is **more** technical and programming-oriented than StackOverflow!

Comment: @Chris: How do you figure? If the question includes source code, it probably belongs on Stack Overflow. Seems technical to me.

Comment: @Code Gray, @Chris Shouts - What Cody said is what I meant; SO tends to focus on specific programming problems.

Comment: See also [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CSS is what styles the web. HTML is what defines the structure.

You can read books, but nothing will help you as much as experience. I have tried to read books, but they don't help me at all. Building little test websites which perform a single function (like a block-based layout, or a three column layout, etc.) helped me learn CSS and HTML.

Play around with HTML and CSS. You can't learn without experience.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ***need*** to learn CSS along with HTML however your markup will be unstyled without it.

You can put inline style attributes on your element tags like so

```
<span style="color: red; width: 100px; background-color: blue;">
    This is the span text
</span>
```

however for anything non trivial, you will almost certainly want to utilize external CSS style sheets for styling, allowing you to apply styles in a uniform fashion

Comment: And likewise, you don't *need* breaks for a car to work but I wouldn't give that as advice to a beginner car enthusiast :P

Comment: Driving a car without working brakes is illegal in most countries whereas the internet police aren't going to come down on you for lack of styling :) I agree with what you're saying, however I was only trying to point out that it isn't a necessity but a good idea :)

Comment: Well duh, the Interet police wouldn't do anything; it would be the jurisdiction of the World Wide Web police not the Internet police ;)

Comment: Also, inline style attributes are still CSS... they're just inline CSS. I thik this answer confuses external style sheets with CSS.

Comment: @Richard - technically they're inline style sheet rules for a style sheet language of which CSS is the default style sheet language if no other has been specified. I inferred that the OP was referring to external style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I would checkout [Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059610197X). It has great reviews on Amazon and the Head First book series are really terrific and engaging.

Comment: It was also written in 2005 and thus outdated. [HTML5 & CSS3 for the real world](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/htmlcss1/)

Comment: I had overlooked that fact. Still, for a beginner it should be as fine if not a more appropriate introduction given the way that Head First structures their content. HTML4 and CSS2 are still relevant technologies. As for cutting edge, the web just might be the best resource for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good intro to web dev class has to give the student a basic understanding of:

- Validated semantic HTML
- CSS selectors
- CSS properties
- JavaScript as an object oriented language with first-class functions
- The Document Object Model
- JavaScript/DOM events
- HTTP protocol
- The difference between HTTP methods (GET is safe etc...)
- Dynamic web sites (CGI or something similar)
- XSRF and XSS attacks - since they are the most basic and common attacks on the web and no web developer should not know about them.

So here are the books I've found helpful for each of those topics:

- Refactoring HTML by Elliotte Rusty Harold (extra points for being Martin Fowler series! http://martinfowler.com/books.html#refactoringHtml )
- CSS in Easy Steps by Mike McGrath (http://www.ineasysteps.com/books/details/?184078301x )
- Learning JavaScript (O'Reilly Media http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527464 - other people seem to think low of this book but it taught me everything I know)
- Programming PHP by Rasmus Lerdorf, Kevin Tatroe and Peter MacIntyre - specifically Chapter 7: Web Techniques (O'Reilly Media http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926103 )
- Essential PHP Security by Chris Shiflett (O'Reilly Media http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006563/ )

It should be noted that two of these books are about PHP. PHP is not a necessity for understanding web development - there are many other alternative server-side technologies which are just as good.

However, those books have good chapters on more general web concepts (such as HTTP and XSS etc...) hence why they're on my list for general web dev.

Comment: You should mention that PHP is an optional backend. And that there are other back ends available.

Comment: I wouldn't say "Some are even better" I would say each backend is good at a specific task and they all have disadvantages / advantages (That's a bigger topic, feel free to ask the [PHP guys](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) in chat about that)

Comment: @Raynos - Ya, but I would :P (j/k... it's a fair point; removed it)

Answer (score 0):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) has a lot of basic tutorials on the most common web technologies. I would suggest starting there for introductions. A lot of these technologies are so dependent on one another that you can't really just learn a single technology without coming into contact with others.

That said, you should get an understanding of HTML before starting anything. IMHO, it is inneffective to read from a book, then with that knowledge, try to create something. Start your project with whatever understanding you have... It will be hard. But you've got the entire internet at your disposal (which introduces/links you to a lot of useful information in a connected way (more so than a book)). Learning as you go is good because you'll learn exactly what you need, nothing more. Be prepared for a lot of going back and improving.

I learned from the web, not a book, so I can't help you there. Good luck!

Comment: w3schools is a horrible, factually inaccurate website. [Follow the campaign](http://w3fools.com/). [Learn from Mozilla instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn)

Comment: @Raynos It has basic tutorials that worked fine for me. That didn't deserve a down vote.

Comment: @chrislegend It has basic tutorials that don't cover anything important about anything important.

Comment: @zirak ...in your opinion. it introduces topics, (you get a feel for what a technology does without too much detail), and then it is up to you where you go from there.

Comment: @chrislegend It fails to deliver real-world uses, doesn't warn you squat about real security hazards (XSS, SQL injection, unsafe eval, semi-colon insertion in js, cross-browser compatibility etc) and also teaches you a lot of bad stuff (hello document.write). As a reference for something it may be a decent resource sometimes (MDC is much better), but as a general tutorial? Nope.

Comment: The only value w3schools has is the fact its a content farm. Lots of low quality content but it's all in one place.

Comment: That's my point... It's not gonna teach you how to be a web developer, but it provides a consolidated place for a taste of everything. Seeing as the spjack has no programming experience, I think it's a good place to start and see what's out there. Is that so bad?